# Terraform Error: The "remote" backend does not support resource targeting at this time

Tags: terraform

Does Terraform Cloud support the `-target` flag when running `terraform plan...`?

It doesn't seem like there's an option to turn on or off this feature in Terraform Cloud. I'm wondering if this means that Terraform Cloud *as a whole* does not support Module targeting, or if there is an option in *my instance* of Terraform Cloud that turns off this feature.

Expected Result: Terraform successfully creates the plan.

Actual Result: Terraform reports the following error:

```
Error: Resource targeting is currently not supported

The "remote" backend does not support resource targeting at this time.
```

### Edit 9/30/19:

I'm using Terraform Cloud's "Remote Executor" and Terraform version 0.12.9.

Comment: Could you provide more info, like, which version of terraform are you using? I didn't face the above error

Comment: @AndyAldo I should have specified that I'm using the Remote Executor in Terraform Cloud. I only get this error when I try to use the Remote Executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/a8d01e3940b406a3c974bfaffd0ca5f534363cc7/backend/remote/backend_plan.go#L73 you see that there is an explicit check in Terraform Cloud backend that disables `Plan targeting`

In the same piece of code you can find all checks and limitations that are currently in effect in Terraform Cloud.

If you need those features, you can migrate your backend to something like aws s3: https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html

To learn more about backends refer to: https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# main.tf

resource "null_resource" "test" {
}

resource "null_resource" "test2" {
}

terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "<my-org>"

    workspaces {
      name = "<my-workspace>"
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't face the error above when running terraform plan:

```sh
❯ terraform plan -target=null_resource.test -out=plan.tfplan 
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.test will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

This plan was saved to: plan.tfplan

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "plan.tfplan"

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Here is my version:

```sh
❯ terraform version  
Terraform v0.12.6
+ provider.null v2.1.2

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.12.9. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```